# frontend: how-to access a dictionary and save a key's value in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webapp that its backend is written in Python and renders some html for the frontend users.

What I would like to achieve is:

1. when a user makes a `POST` request to `/token`, the backend replies with a JSON document `{"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}`; this is already in place
2. after the above takes place, every subsequent request / navigation to the webapp, should set a `header` named `Authorization` equal to `Bearer <access_token>` to every `GET`, `POST`, etc. request that it does; not important for the time being
3. can you advise and describe how to maintain a single variable client-side called `access_token` that its default value is `null`, but when doing `POST` to `/token`, then the variable `access_token` is initialised and never changes through navigation, unless the end user makes another `POST` request to `/token` again to reset the `access_token` to the new value ?

I am not familiar with `jQuery` or `javascript` much. Can you suggest how to initialise, set, reset a variable (and just print it, for example, using `console.log`) based on the background information above ?

Comment: You can store the token in local storage, or in cookies, either would work. Then, when you go to make an ajax call, you'll retrieve the value from whichever you used,  and add it to the outgoing ajax request. How exactly you do that willl depend on what specific ajax implementation you use. For example google "add auth token to jquery.ajax" and you'll find the right syntax for that library

Comment: thanks @WesleySmith would you be so kind to describe how the `jQuery` snippet that accesses the `access_token` value and initialises, sets, resets the local storage variable looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the token in local storage, or in cookies, either would work. Then, when you go to make an ajax call, you'll retrieve the value from whichever you used, and add it to the outgoing ajax request. How exactly you do that willl depend on what specific ajax implementation you use. For example google "add auth token to jquery.ajax" and you'll find the right syntax for that library

Something like this would work:

```
// do initial login and get token
var token = response.access_token;

// store it in local storage
localStorage.setItem('apiKey', token);

// ... navigate around and what not...


// later, when you need to make another call, get the token 
var token = localStorage.getItem('apiKey');

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    //.. other props as needed...
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        /* set the Authorization header with the token */
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    },
    success: function (data) {
      // do something cool with data
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // handle errors ...
    }
});
```